# Multilines In Richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, multiline

Alright, I have a richtextbox that contains this.

```
line1
line2
```

As a test I used the code below to confirm that my program can read the lines but it doesn't.

```
If RichTextBox1.lines.Contains("Line1" & vbcrlf & "Line2") Then
    MsgBox("hi")
End If
```

I've tried vbcrlf, environment.newline, char(32), vbcrlf & _.

thinking that either lines or contains is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`RichTextBox.Lines` returns an array with one element for each line of text.  `Contains("Line1" & VbCrLf & "Line2")` will look for an element in the array that matches that string, but your array has one element with "line1" and a second element with "line2", not a single element with both.  By the way, "Line1" will not match "line1", as there is a case difference between the two strings.

If you want to read the lines of the RichtTextBox, you can loop through it:

```
For Each line As String In RichTextBox1.Lines
    ' Do something here 
Next
```

[RichTextBox.Lines Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

have you try this

```
If RichTextBox1.lines.Contains("Line1" & vblf & "Line2") Then
    MsgBox("hi")
End If
```